# Setting a charts data range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am helping to revamp the Excel sheets the management team uses for business analysis. I am making a dashboard page that displays the data in an easy to digest manner. They add data to the data pages, hit a button, and it refreshes the values.

My issue is getting the chart to automatically update the ranges in it. The chart has two data series, bids submitted and bids won, plotted against weeks. As the weeks in the year go, the chart will have more data in it.

My code looks like this

```
Sub Dashboard_Tool()

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Myvalue As String
Dim lastcell As Range
Dim B As Byte
Dim P As Byte

'this is to get the bid info
Set Sh1 = Worksheets("New Dashboard")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("MI Dashboard")

For B = 1 To 12
    Myvalue = sh2.Cells(9, B + 9)
    Sh1.Cells(26, 3).Value = Myvalue
    Sh1.Cells(26, 2).Value = "This Month (" & sh2.Cells(8, B + 9) & ")"
    If sh2.Cells(9, B + 10).Value = "" Then Exit For
Next B

Set lastcell = sh2.Cells(9, B + 9)
Debug.Print lastcell.Value
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Bid Chart").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='MI Dashboard'!$K$9:" & Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column)
```

It is the last lime I have quoted that is the issue. No matter which way I write the expression I get the same error

> Run-Time error '1004':
>   Application defined or object defined error

I tried rewriting this line of code in a number of ways. The variable for this is the column. The row is always number 9.

Comment: Why not make the data the enter into a table, and base the chart off of the table? Excel is smart enough to auto-expand things entered into a table, and we could do this with pure built-in features instead of writing code

Comment: the data is being taken from an already existing table, which has more in its rows than just the data I need. I tried making a table within a table, but excel wouldn't let me, otherwise I would have done that. but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It looks like you got a solution, but two other solutions: 1) Add a new column that's a boolean for if you want the data or not, and make a pivot chart, filtering on the boolean column - 2) Use power query to filter instead, and make the chart off of the new table generated by power query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last row wants a range address string assigned to the `.Value`, but the error is likely occurring because the string you're building isn't a valid address.

```
"='MI Dashboard'!$K$9:" & Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column)
```

is concatenating the first part with the ***value*** of the cell at lastcell.row, column (of the current active sheet, by the way).

What you want is something closer to this:

```
"='MI Dashboard'!$K$9:" & sh2.Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column).Address
```

My suggestion is to create a string for the address you can check before the assignment to the `.Value`, just so you know it's correct.

```
Dim seriesAddress As String
seriesAddress = "='MI Dashboard'!$K$9:" & sh2.Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column).Address
Debug.Print seriesAddress
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = seriesAddress
```

Comment: that is literally what I needed, thanks! it was the .address function! I am still newish to vba and completely forgot this existed and no amount of googling how to make it equal to the cells actual range would give me the .address function. guess it's because I didn't use the word address in my search. thanks for the answer and your time